# USERNAME and PASSWORD freezes, When wrong login credentials are entered twice

Tags: jquery, ios, html, css

When wrong login credentials are entered twice, the text field of **USERNAME** and **PASSWORD** freezes. i.e, I am not able to type in any character in the input filed

1. App: Native(iOS)
2. Tech: HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Javascript, Ajax
3. Username and password are validated through jQuery.

Below is the screen shot for the app login interface

[image]

```js
$('#btn_submit').on('touchend',function(){
 
    $('#email,#password').blur();
 $('#email,#password').css('cursor','none');
    login=0;
  $.getJSON( "js/login.json", function( data ) {
        for(i=0;i<data.login.length;i++){
            if(($("input[name='email']").val() == data.login[i].username) && ($("input[name='password']").val() == data.login[i].password) ){
                localStorage.setItem('username', $("input[name='email']").val());
                setVariables();
                $('#LoginScreen').hide();
                $("#admin").show();
                login=1;
                return;
            }
            else{
               
               //login=0;
            }
            
        }
         if(login==0){
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Please check the username and password!", "error");
        }

    });
   
    return false;
});

$('#home-btn').on("touchend", function() {
$('#container').load('main.html',function(){
   if($('#container').attr('data-user')=='internal')
      {
        $('#admin #section04,#admin #section03').show();
       }
   $('#LoginScreen').hide();
   $("#admin").show();
   $('#container').attr('data-page','index');
        
});
}
```

```css
.customer_login {
  width: 308px;
  height: 270px;    
  top: 200px;
  left: 370px;
  position: absolute;
}
.customer_login .form-row{
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
textarea:focus, input:focus, button:focus{
    outline: none;
} 
.customer_login input{
    border: 1px solid #414c60;
    padding: 17px 19px;
    width: 267px;
    font-size: 15.5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #010918;
    opacity: 0.4;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
.login_title {
  width: 248px;
  height: 49px;
  background-image: url(../images/title_ico.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-size: 32px 32px;
  background-color: #1d7e93;
  top: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStdLt';
}
.customer_login button {
    width: 134px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url(../images/submit_arr.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 108px center;
    background-size: 16px 17.5px;
    background-color: #6c8f24;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 44.5px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 172px;
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStdLt';
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer_login">
                <div class="login_title">Sign in</div>
                <form method="get" action="#">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="User ID">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="●●●●●">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <button type="submit" id="btn_submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: I assume the missing `$` before `('#btn_submit')` is a copy-paste error?

Comment: Yes, It was copy paste error. Fixed. Thanx